# Translation invariance of cross product.

Tags: linear-algebra

For two vectors $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Their cross product $a \times b$ is a vector that orthogonal to the plane spanned by them. If both $a, b$ was translated by a vector $c\in \mathbb{R}^3$, would the cross product subject to a simple translation?

$(a+c)\times(b+c) ?= (a\times b)+c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross product is distributive, and $c\times c=0$, so

$$ (a+c)\times(b+c)= a\times b+a\times c+c\times b. $$

The only way this equals $a\times b+c$ is if

$$ a\times c+c\times b=c. $$

This isn't possible if $c\ne 0$ though; the left side is perpendicular to the right side!